# Fatal error: Uncaught ArgumentCountError

Tags: php

Me pueden dar una mano con este error? Soy nuevo en esto..

> Fatal error: Uncaught ArgumentCountError: Too few arguments to
>   function Base::bind(), 2 passed in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\guiacordoba\app\modelos\Usuario.php on line 21 and
>   exactly 3 expected in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\guiacordoba\app\librerias\Base.php:39 Stack trace: #0
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\guiacordoba\app\modelos\Usuario.php(21):
>   Base->bind(':nombre', 'jhghj') #1
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\guiacordoba\app\controladores\Paginas.php(27):
>   Usuario->agregarUsuario(Array) #2
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\guiacordoba\app\librerias\Core.php(51):
>   Paginas->agregar() #3 C:\xampp\htdocs\guiacordoba\public\index.php(6):
>   Core->__construct() #4 {main} thrown in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\guiacordoba\app\librerias\Base.php on line 39

Base.php

```
<?php

  //Clase para conectarse a la base de datos y ejecutar consultas PDO
  class Base{
    private $host = DB_HOST;
    private $usuario = DB_USUARIO;
    private $password = DB_PASSWORD;
    private $db_nombre = DB_NOMBRE;

    private $dbh;
    private $stmt;
    private $error;

    public function __construct(){
      //configurar conexion
      $dsn = 'mysql:host=' . $this->host . ';dbname=' .$this->db_nombre;

      $opciones = array(
        PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT => true,
        PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION
      );

      //Crear una instancia de PDO
      try {
          $this->dbh = new PDO($dsn, $this->usuario, $this->password, $opciones);
          $this->dbh->exec('set names utf8');

      } catch (PDOException $e) {
          $this->error = $e->getMessage();
          echo $this->error;
      }
    }

    //Preparamos la consulta
    public function query($sql){
      $this->stmt = $this->dbh->prepare($sql);
    }

    //Vinculamos la consulta con bind
    public function bind($parametro, $valor, $tipo){
      if (is_null($tipo)) {
        switch (true) {
          case is_int($valor):
            $tipo = PDO::PARAM_INT;
          break;
          case is_bool($valor):
            $tipo = PDO::PARAM_BOOL;
          break;
          case is_null($valor):
            $tipo = PDO::PARAM_NULL;
          break;
          default:
            $tipo = PDO::PARAM_STR;
          break;
        }
      }
      $this->stmt->bindValue($parametro, $valor, $tipo);
    }

    //Ejecuta la consulta
    public function execute(){
      return $this->stmt->execute();
    }

    //Obtener los registros de la consulta
    public function registros(){
      $this->execute();
      return $this->stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
    }

    //Obtener un unico registro
    public function registro(){
      $this->execute();
      return $this->stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
    }

    //Obtener cantidad de filas con el metodo rowCount
    public function rowCount(){
      return $this->stmt->rowCount();
    }
  }
```

Usuario.php

```
<?php

  class Usuario{
    private $db;

    public function __construct(){
      $this->db = new Base;
    }

    public function obtenerUsuarios(){
      $this->db->query('SELECT * FROM clientes');

      $resultados = $this->db->registros();

      return $resultados;
    }

    public function agregarUsuario($datos){
      $this->db->query('INSERT INTO clientes (nombre, email, telefono) VALUES (:nombre, :email, :telefono)');

      $this->db->bind(':nombre', $datos['nombre']);
      $this->db->bind(':email', $datos['email']);
      $this->db->bind(':telefono', $datos['telefono']);

      if ($this->db->execute()) {
        return true;
      }else{
        return false;
      }
    }
  }
```

Espero me puedan ayudar, muchas gracias!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema es que tu funcion `bind()` espera **3** parametros : `($parametro, $valor, $tipo)`:

Pero solo le pasas 2 en las siguientes funciones:

```
$this->db->bind(':nombre', $datos['nombre']);
$this->db->bind(':email', $datos['email']);
$this->db->bind(':telefono', $datos['telefono']);
```

Y para que no te de error tienes que:

- Pasarle **3** parametros
- O sino preparar la funcion para funcionar sin la necesidad de introducir los 3 parametros

Answer (score 0):

El problema es que PHP espera que en los argumentos de la funcion exista. Si no se lo pasa os no lo inicializas, no existen.

aqui le estas enviando 2

```
$this->db->bind(':nombre', $datos['nombre']);
```

aqui espera 3

```
public function bind($parametro, $valor, $tipo)
```

Lo que yo te propongo es que incialices el argumento para que en el caso de que no se lo pases, al menos exista.

```
public function bind($parametro, $valor, $tipo = NULL) {
```

Tienes mas informacion sobre argumentos [aqui](http://php.net/manual/es/functions.arguments.php)

Comment: Muchas gracias a todos